# .htaccess mod_rewrite: difference between the -s and -f conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used the apache rewrite module a lot, but now I stumbled upon these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

The first line uses the -s condition. The second uses the -f condition. In the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) it reads:

For -f

> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.

For -s

> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file with size greater than zero.

I found the two conditions using [Julian Pömp’s htaccess generator for angular](https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator).

So, what is the use of the `-s` condition (file with size) if there is already the `-f` condition (file exists)? It seems a little redundant to both check for the existence of a file and for the existence of a file with a size greater than zero.  All files will pass the `-f` condition so there seems to be no need for the `-s` condition check…

Comment: It is redundant check. `-f` or `-s` alone should be suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it's redundant. If I use both conditions it shouldn't matter if the file size is greater than 0 or not. I'll change it to only `-f`.